# How to bind gridview after Page_Load?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to bind a gridview after the page has finished loading (after Page_Load), so not on the Page_Load event handler, but after that.

Comment: Immediately after the page has finished loading, or in response to a user event?

Comment: immediately after the page has finished loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
         Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete
            If Not IsPostBack Then
                Me.DataBind()
            End If
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub DataBind()

           Me.Grid.Datasource = Somedata          

           MyBase.DataBind()    

        End Sub
```

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean. The Gridview is bound to a datasource on the server side. You can bind the source at any point between `Page_Init` and the end of `Page_Load`, if I recall correctly.

jQuery on the other hand runs on the client side and therefore binding a datasource to the Gridview at this point is not possible.